# What pattern could I use to bind a getter property to the template (to prevent continuous reevaluation)

Tags: angular

**Background**

In ASP.NET MVC, we have the `ViewModel` pattern to display just a select number of properties from the domain object in the view. Sometimes, these properties are calculated based on other properties, e.g.:

```
public int Total {
  get {
    return this.Count * this.Price;
  }
}
```

**Issue**

I'm trying to follow a similar pattern in `Angular` - given the JSON object from the server, I convert it to a class (my domain object), I then create a specialized `ViewModel` class with properties calculated based on other properties, e.g.:

```
public get total: number {
  return this.count * this.price;
}
```

The issue is that, when I bind such a property to the template, Angular continuously evaluates it, and I'm concerned that it might impact performance. This continuous evaluation is sensible because the value of the property must react to changes of the "dependent" properties. So if either "count" or "price" change, I do need to display the new value of "total".

But I would hope to update the value of *total* on demand, instead of forcing Angular to continuously evaluate it.

What other alternatives do I have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your concerns are valid. You shouldn't do that.

Just assign the result to a field and bind to that field instead.

Angular evaluates bound expressions every time change detection runs.
You can try to reduce the number of change detection runs using `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` or `ChangeDetectorRef.detach()`, but it's still better to use a field.
Change detection with fields is very efficient.

```
_count:number;
set count(value:number) {
  this._count = value;
  this.calcTotal();
}
get count() {return this._count;}

_price:number;
set price(value:number) {
  this._price = value;
  this.calcTotal();
}
get price() {return this._price;}


_total:number;
get total() {return this._total;}

_calcTotal(): number {
  this._total = this.count * this.price;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Günter! So I will bind to "total", which returns an already calculated value. And when my "dependent" fields change, I will recalculate the total. Did I get it right? Thanks again.

Comment: Exactly. This way you only do work (calculation) when it's actually necessary, and change detection can work the most efficient way.