# Angular 4: displaying "aggregate" properties in the template (one-way)

Tags: angular

I have `view model` classes that I construct from JSON objects coming from the server. I then bind these classes to templates.

In some cases, I need to add additional properties to these classes (i.e. in addition to those in the JSON object). For example, I might need to display the total of an order:

```
public total(): number {
  return this.price * this.count;
}
```

[In this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47162246/what-pattern-could-i-use-to-bind-a-getter-property-to-the-template-to-prevent-c) I learned about binding to properties such as this.

However, I'm wondering if there are other alternatives that could be more in line with Angular. For example, I'm wondering if I could use pipes to display these sort of "aggregate" properties, instead of creating a new property altogether.

My question is - what would be the Angular way to solve this problem?

Comment: The way you're doing it is perfectly 'Angular' and I would say you're doing it a very good way. Business logic should be kept in your class which is what you're doing. No need to look for an alternative.

Comment: don't abuse pipes. Pipes should be seen primarily as formatters, like adding commas to a number or formatting as currency or dates.  The "angular way" is to make what you're doing very transparent and obvious, and pipes aren't a great way of doing that in the case of actual calculations, because I'd need too know more than I should.  using getters is an angular approach.  The somewhat better or more sophisticated method though might be to build in the logic to calculate these "aggregate" properties when they need to be calculated instead of relying on change detection to do it for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends on who expensive the aggregate is to compute, and how many such aggregates will coexist on the view.

- If the performance overhead is negligible, your solution looks fine to me, since it is easy to write and maintain, and the value is guaranteed to be correct with little effort on your part.
- If the performance overhead is significant, you'll want to cache aggregates and recompute them whenever inputs change. This additional logic can get quite complex, even with the help of RXJS, but can be necessary to achieve acceptable performance.

In your example, performing a single multiplication per change detection run should not measurably (let alone noticeably) impact performance, but it would be questionable to filter a list of 10'000 objects in every change detection run, or compute the total of 10'000 order items.

If in doubt, I'd implement the simple approach, and measure whether it meets performance goals. Or to quote Donald Knuth:

> Programmers waste enormous amounts of time thinking about, or worrying about, the speed of noncritical parts of their programs, and these attempts at efficiency actually have a strong negative impact when debugging and maintenance are considered. We should forget about small efficiencies, say about 97% of the time: premature optimization is the root of all evil. Yet we should not pass up our opportunities in that critical 3%.

Comment: Thanks for the quote!